# Is there a way in PowerShell to get the default value of a script parameter?

Tags: powershell

For launching scripts with `Start-Job` it is required to use the correct order of parameters within the array provided to `-ArgumentList`.

Consider this script:

```bsh
# $script = c:\myScripts.ps1
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$ScriptName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$Path,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String[]]$MailTo,
    [String]$LogFolder = "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\Log",
    [String]$ScriptAdmin = 'gmail@hchucknoris.com'
)
```

We would like to know how it is possible to retrieve the default values set in `$LogFolder` and `$ScriptAdmin`?

My attempt where I can't seem to find it:

```bsh
  $scriptParameters = (Get-Command $script).Parameters.GetEnumerator() | 
    Where-Object { $psBuildInParameters -notContains $_.Key }
    
    foreach ($p in $scriptParameters.GetEnumerator()) {
        'Name: {0} Type: {1} Mandatory: {2} DefaultValue: x' -f $p.Value.Name, $p.Value.ParameterType, $p.Value.Attributes.Mandatory
    }
```

If we have the default value we can use `Start-Job` more flexible in case we want to start a job with only the mandatory parameters and say `$ScriptAdmini`, but want to keep the value in `$LogFolder` and not blank it out with an empty string because we need to respect the order or the arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Ast parsing for this:

```
$script = 'c:\myScripts.ps1'

# Parse the script file for objects based on Ast type
$parsed = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile($script,[ref]$null,[ref]$null)

# Extract only parameter ast objects
$params = $parsed.FindAll({$args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.ParameterAst]},$true)

$params | Foreach-Object {
    $name = $_.Name.VariablePath.ToString()
    $type = $_.StaticType.FullName
    # Convoluted because the property values themselves present strings rather than booleans where the values are $false or false 
    $mandatory = [bool]($_.Attributes | where {$_.NamedArguments.ArgumentName -eq 'Mandatory'} |% {$_.NamedArguments.Argument.SafeGetValue()})
    $DefaultValue = $_.DefaultValue.Value
    "Name: {0} Type: {1} Mandatory: {2} DefaultValue: {3}" -f $name,$type,$mandatory,$DefaultValue 
}
```

See [System.Management.Automation.Language Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) for other potential abstract syntax tree types.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the [`System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.parametermetadata) instances reported by `(Get-Command $script).Parameters` do *not* include information about parameter *default values*.

Even if they did, you'd be faced with the problem of having to *evaluate* those values, given that they can be *expandable strings* or *expressions*.

If you do want to go that route, [AdminOfThings's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64358608/45375) shows you how to use PowerShell's own parser via the PowerShell SDK to get the default values.

Taking a step back: There are two ways of **overcoming the inability to pass *named* arguments to [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job)**:

- In **PowerShell [Core] v6+**, you can **use postpositional `&`**, the [background operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#background-operator-), which **allows you to use normal argument-passing**:

```
# PSv6+ only: appending "&" to a pipeline turns it into a job.
$job = & $script -ScriptName foo -Path bar -MailTo someone@example.org &
```

- In **Windows PowerShell**, you can use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) as a **workaround**:

```
$job = Start-Job { $argsHash = $args[0]; & $using:script @argsHash } -Args @{
          ScriptName = 'foo'
          Path = 'bar';
          MailTo = 'someone@example.org' 
       }
```

Note: If you don't mind defining an auxiliary variable in the *caller*'s scope, the alternative is:

```
$argsHash = 
@{
          ScriptName = 'foo'
          Path = 'bar';
          MailTo = 'someone@example.org' 
}

$job = Start-Job { & $using:script @using:argsHash }
```