# Get the default value for a custom module in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I know that you can get the parameters from a commandlet by running

```
(Get-Command My-CommandGoesHere).Parameters.Keys
```

I also know you should be able to get the values for a ValidateSet within a script if you run

```
(Get-Command My-CommandGoesHere).Parameters["MyParameter"].Attributes.ValidValues
```

Is it possible to get the default value of a parameter? Suppose I have a commandlet that begins with

```
param(  
    [string]$MyVariable = "MyDefaultValue"
)
```

Is there any way to, outside of this commandlet, get the "MyDefaultValue" somehow? I could do something like

```
(((Get-Command My-CommandGoesHere).Definition -split "param\(")[1] -split "\)")[0]
```

but this only works if I have one variable, and that I know what the variable name is. The closest I think I've gotten would be something like

```
$ParameterName = "MyVariable"
$CommandletDefinition = ((Get-Command My-CommandGoesHere).Definition -split "`n").Trim()
$ParameterStart = $CommandletDefinition.IndexOf("param(")
$ParameterEnd = $CommandletDefinition.IndexOf(")")
$ParameterSection = @()
for ($i=$ParameterStart+1; $i-le $ParameterEnd-1 ;$i++) {
    $ParameterSection += $CommandletDefinition[$i]
}

[string]$ParameterValue = [string]($ParameterSection -match $ParameterName)
(($ParameterValue -split "$ParameterName = """)[1] -split """")[0]
```

But that feels like a really bad workaround to something that should probably be available with a one-liner. Is there a better way to extract the default value from a parameter in a commandlet/module?

Comment: Yes that is the correct way, but you better use the [AST](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language) parser, see: [Is there a way in PowerShell to get the default value of a script parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64358608/1701026)

Comment: How did that not show up when I searched for "powershell output default value of parameter" I have no idea, but that definitely looks like a better way of finding it :) In my case I already have the module loaded so I use ::ParseInput instead of ::ParseFile which seems to give me the correct output. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I knew the issue existed already and I also know that the StackOverflow search doesn't always find where I am looking for either. Therefore I often use just google instead: [`PowerShell get default parameter site:stackoverflow.com`](https://www.google.com/search?q=PowerShell+get+default+parameter+site%3Astackoverflow.com)